# Crashlytics Missing NDK symbols with android app bundle

Tags: crashlytics-android

Firebase Crashlytics symbol upload not working with android app bundle (AAB)

The setup was done following the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"  
 android:value="false" />
```

`build.gradle` :

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.5'
```

for crashlytics ndk support

```
Fabric.with(Fabric.Builder(this)
                    .kits(Crashlytics(), CrashlyticsNdk())
                    .build())
```

Expect the native crashes to show up on crashlytics. Do not see any native crashes.

Comment: Are your crashes symbolicated in the Google Play console? We've recently enabled AAB and added arm64 libs, and we're seeing that the majority of crashes in the Google Play console are unsymbolicated.

Comment: Try android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false. It fixed problems for me with symbolication in the Google Play Console: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55966582/google-play-crash-logs-not-symbolicated-with-android-app-bundle

Comment: I had the same problem as you , no symbols on google play as well. Did ```android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false``` in the ```gradle.properties``` also fix it on firebase?

Comment: We don't really use Crashlytics, we only looked into it when we had symbolication issues in Google Play, we thought switching to Crashlytics might solve our problems and had symbolication issues there too. `enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false` fixed our Google Play issue, but we haven't gone back to Crashlytics yet to see if it made any difference (not sure if we'll bother checking as there's no longer a pressing need for us).

Comment: I get this warning when trying the option : 
" WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported."

Comment: We get that warning too and have been living with it without issue. The warning may be suppressed in the latest Android Studio Canary (although it's slightly ambiguous exactly which suggestion was implemented already): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130029001

Answer (score 7):

As suggested in the comments, you need to enable uncompressed native libs in order to get symbolication of native crashes working in Firebase Crashlytics.

Add this to your app's `gradle.properties`:

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```